# Require all steps in Google Analytics goals funnel?

Tags: google-analytics, conversions, goal-tracking, goals

I've a funnel with 3 steps. Currently seeing some conversions "missing" step 2 and GA still records it as conversion.

Is there a way to require a user to pass through all steps before GA considers it a proper conversion? It seems GA only allows the step 1 to be required, are there ways to properly implement what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the way that Google Analytics works to require all steps of the funnel.   Any time a user makes it to a later step, Google Analytics "back fills" any missing steps in-between and it will appear that they happened in the reporting.

From https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2976313?hl=en

> #### Backfilling Funnel Steps
>
> What happens if someone skips one of the steps in the funnel?
>
> The Funnel Visualization report backfills any skipped steps between the step at which the user entered the funnel and the step at which the user exited the funnel.
>
> For example, let's say your funnel is defined as /step1 > /step2 > /step3 > goal, and a user navigates from /step2 to goal, skipping /step1 and /step3. In the Funnel Visualization report, you'd see an entrance to /step 2, a continuation to /step 3, and a continuation to goal.

The only way to prevent this is to modify your site to make it impossible for a user to navigate to further steps.  If you have alternate paths to the conversion it might be possible to mark the funnel path with a parameter.   For example your funnel might look like:

- `/landing`
- `/step-1`
- `/step-2`
- `/thank-you`

If there are other ways of getting to the conversion (thank you) you might want to make your funnel:

- `/landing`
- `/step-1?from=landing`
- `/step-2?from=landing`
- `/thank-you?from=landing`

You would have to modify your site to pass that "from" parameter only when the user comes from that particular funnel source.

Comment: Thanks! I guess adding `?from=landing` is the easiest way to this.